# Trigger.io with Parse.com whilst using Windows - Certificates Issue

Tags: mobile, trigger.io, parse-platform

I am having difficulties in using a PC to generate the required certficates used between trigger.io and parse.com.

I can create the one that works with trigger.io (with a password) however the Parse.com website requires that I upload a certificate (p12) without a password. Which is it?

I have openssl on my PC, therefore I can use that to help me out :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These two certificates are actually quite different:

The one for Trigger.io is your developer certificate which identifies you and enables you to create builds using certain provisioning profiles.

The one for Parse is a push notification SSL certificate, which enables you or other services to send push notifications to your apps.

Glad to hear the Trigger.io certificate is working for you: have you see Parse's documentation on this? https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

You should be able to use the method we described in [our docs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/tools/ios-windows.html) to create your signing request; for steps 8-10, you can use certmgr.msc to export a .pfx, which is actually the same thing as a .p12.